# Property in Ember Service undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a service for a business calendar where a property is not available to a computed property but is available in a method.

In the code below the property *calendars* is not defined when the computed *businessYear* property is accessed. On the other hand, *calendars* is defined when the *year()* method is called.

The *currentYear* property is used elsewhere so init() is called and the store promise is resolved before *businessYear* is accessed.

I've debugged this and developer tools shows that *this.calenders* is defined in watch variables but is still undefined in the computed property.  It's almost like the computed property is being executed in another context.  I'm probably missing something really basic but just don't see it.

app/services/business-calendar.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import moment from 'moment';

const { computed, inject: { service }, get, set } = Ember;

const findCalendar = (date, calendars) => {
    let p1, p13

   return calendars.find(function (item, index, enumerable) {
       p1 = moment(get(item, 'p1'));
       p13 = moment(get(item, 'p13'));
       return moment.range(p1, p13).contains(date);
   })
}

export default Ember.Service.extend({
   store: service(),
   calendars: [],

currentDate: computed(() => {
    return moment();
}),

currentYear: computed('currentDate', () => {
    return moment(get(this, 'currentDate')).year();
}),

businessYear: computed(() => {
    let calendar = findCalendar(moment(), get(this, 'calendars'));
    return get(this.calendar, 'year');
}),

init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    get(this, 'store').findAll('calendar').then((recs) => {
        set(this, 'calendars', recs);
    })
},

year(date) {
    let d = moment(date);
      var calendar = findCalendar(d, get(this, 'calendars’));
       return get(calendar, 'year');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to feedback on the Ember Slack feed the issue is the use of arrow functions in the computed properties. This creates a different 'this' or context.  The working code is below.  Note even thought the *currentDate* and *currentYear* computed properties were working, all arrow functions were removed for code consistency.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import moment from 'moment';

const { computed, inject: { service }, get, set } = Ember;

const findCalendar = (date, calendars) => {
    let p1, p13

return calendars.find(function (item, index, enumerable) {
    p1 = moment(get(item, 'p1'));
    p13 = moment(get(item, 'p13'));
    return moment.range(p1, p13).contains(date);
 })
}

export default Ember.Service.extend({
   store: service(),
   calendars: [],

currentDate: computed(function() {
   return moment();
}),

currentYear: computed('currentDate', function() {
    return moment(get(this, 'currentDate')).year();
}),

businessYear: computed(function() {
   let calendar = findCalendar(moment(), get(this, 'calendars'));
   return get(this.calendar, 'year');
}),

init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    get(this, 'store').findAll('calendar').then((recs) => {
        set(this, 'calendars', recs);
    })
},

year(date) {
    let d = moment(date);
    var calendar = findCalendar(d, get(this, 'calendars’));
    return get(calendar, 'year');
 }
});
```